# В ходе проверки кода возникает ошибка, однако я не знаю где

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

[Условие взято отсюда.](https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=634&chapterid=612)

> Даны N целых чисел X1, X2, ..., XN. Расставить между ними знаки "+" и
>   "-" так, чтобы значение получившегося выражения было равно заданному
>   целому S.

**Входные данные:**

> В первой строке находятся числа N и S. В следующей строке - N чисел
>   через пробел. 2 <= N <= 24, 0 <= Xi <= 50 000 000, -1 000 000 000 <= S
>   <= 1 000 000 000.

**Выходные данные:**

> Если получить требуемый результат невозможно, вывести "No solution",
>   если можно, то вывести равенство. Если решение не единственное,
>   вывести любое.

---

Во время проверки кода возникают ошибки, но я не знаю где.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
#   генерирует массив длины 2**n,
#   где n -- длина каждого элемента
def gena (leng, seed = []):
    res = []
    if len(seed) == 0:
        res.append('+')
        res.append('-')
    else:
        for i in seed:
            res.append(i+'+')
            res.append(i+'-')
    if leng == 1:
        return res
    else:
        return gena(leng = leng - 1, seed = res)

#   ввод чисел
s1 = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
s2 = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))

#start_time = time.time()

#   базовая проверка по четности
#   иногда экономит время
if sum(s2)%2 != s1[1]%2:
    print ("No solution")
else: 
    for i in gena(leng = s1[0] -1):
        e = s2[0]
        for j,g in zip(s2[1:],list(i)):
            if g == "-":
                e -= j
            else:
                e += j
        if e == s1[1]:
            res = i
            break
    if 'res' in locals():
        res += '='
        n = ''
        for i,j in zip(res,s2):
            n += ( str(j) + i)
        n += str(s1[1])
        print (n)
    else:
        print ("No solution")
```

Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста!

Comment: Ошибку и ее стек нужно в вопрос прикладывать, а не в виде скриншота. Т.к. у тех, кто заинтересуется вопросом не будет возможности выделить и скопировать ее, а люди с похоже проблемой не смогут найти ее через поисковик. Под вопросом есть кнопка `править`.

Comment: @gil9red для олимпиадных задач это невозможно в принципе

Comment: @andreymal, у меня на работе прокси не дает посмотреть картинки с imgur, поэтому уже на автомате пишу :)

Comment: Нужно в вопрос добавить входные данные, что вы использовали... Или с своими данными у вас ошибки нет, а вот у проверяющей системы ошибки?

Comment: `gena` рвёт память скорей всего `MemoryError` - уходите к итераторам

Comment: Ваше решение не проходит ограничение по памяти

Comment: @gil9red, с моими данными все хорошо, ошибка возникает при проверке

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо за редактирование, вопрос стал более читабельным.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду использовать yield.